# Youtube API video limited to 50 video's a day?

Tags: youtube-api

We use the youtube API to upload automated generated videos's to youtube and we have a channel with about 32.000 video's at the moment. But since a few days we are not able to upload more then 50 video's a day. Even if try it on my personal account it only allows me to upload no more then 50 video's.

The error we are getting after 50 video is the following and it does not mention any API limits.

```
Failed to start the resumable upload (HTTP 403: youtube.common, Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized.)
```

I logged into the developer console to check the [quotes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLqNH.png) but these are high for objectives. And the [stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoIqI.png) are not showing that we are hitting a API limit at the moment.

I'm not sure what to do at the moment as we are know stuk with generating at least 100 video's a day and are not able to upload these to Youtube. Anny ideas on how we could fix this and verify that we are hitting a daily limit? Is there also a way to increase this 50 video limit?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if your app handles expired tokens to access the API, as the [document](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) stated:

> If the user consents to authorize your application to access those resources, Google returns a token to your application. Depending on your application's type, it either validates the token or exchanges it for a different type of token.
>
> For example, a server-side web application exchanges the returned token for an access token and a refresh token. The access token lets the application authorize requests on the user's behalf, and the refresh token lets the application retrieve a new access token when the original access token expires.

If this doesn't solve your issue, there is a reported [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35919708) that "this behavior is intended; currently you are limited to uploading 100 videos per day." They've also created a feature request to improve the error message.

Hope this helps.